# Excel - fastest macro generate dataset

Tags: vba, excel, dataset, simulation

I have an excel file with:

- in the first worksheet several calculations
- a second worksheet where all relevant data are put together in one row (A2:W2)
- a third worksheet where i gather the data from each simulation/calculation in a new row (= creation of the dataset of 100K simulations)

The macro that I have now does the trick but is get slower the more rows have been copied. I'm looking for a way to do this as clean and quick as possible.
The only things that is needs to do is: copy the datarange from the second worksheet on the first free row of the third worksheet, generate new data, copy data, paste data on first free row, ... .

The macro I have now is for 10K simulations, but if I try to generate more than 100K datasets in one run it slows down incredibly.

Thanks for help/advice/tips. Please keep in mind that I'm a noob with this :(

```
Sub Plus10000()
    '
    ' Plus10000 Macro
    '
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Let x = 0
    Do While x < 10000
        Range("SourceData").Copy

        Sheets("Data").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        x = x + 1
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    '
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You copy and past row by row, which is very slow because each paste action takes a lot of time. But you can just copy and paste in one action multiple times.

```
Sub Plus10000()
    '
    ' Plus10000 Macro
    '
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Range("SourceData").Copy
    Sheets("Data").Range("B1:B10000").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    '
End Sub
```

This will paste your source range from row 1 to 10000.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! This pastes 1000 rows but with identical data. When i work row by row i get a new result/simulation that is added to my dataset. So sadly this will not work.

Comment: @stijngeldof as the pastespecial pastes values in your original and so does the new solution offered, then both should give the same result - unless your original code has been changed....

Comment: Well, if the SourceData is affected by the Data (via Formula) then there is no way besides copy row by row (which takes it's time) or think about another concept (but we cannot tell you how to do that).

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is to avoid to use CLIPBOARD !

If your program run 1 hour and you will do another thing at the same time, your Excel macro will certainly crashes when clipboard is manually changed by user or another program.

The only solution to your problem is to write a complete macro that generate your data without using intermediary sheet, without using Cell's formulas and without using Clipboard !

Answer (score 0):

you could try not to write your sheet cells at every iteration:

```
Sub Plus10000()
    Const nData As Long = 10000 ' set the number of calculations to be done

    ReDim data(1 To nData, 1 To Range("SourceData").Columns.Count) As Variant ' size you data array to mathc the number of calculations and "source" range

    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Do While i < nData
        i = i + 1
        Calculate ' have Excel make a new calculation of your workbook formulas
        For j = 1 To UBound(data, 2) ' fill your data current row with "Source" range current values
            data(i, j) = Range("SourceData").Cells(1, j)
        Next
    Loop
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual ' prevent formula recalculation at subsequent "Data" sheet writing
    Sheets("Data").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(UBound(data), UBound(data, 2)).Value = data ' fill "data" sheet with data array values in one shot
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic ' set Excel automatic calculation back on
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I copied the macro in my file, it runs but no rows with data are added to the worksheet 'Data'. In the worksheet 'Macro', i named the range with info "Sourcedata". Do i need to make some adjustments?

Comment: Be sure you're starting the macro when the sheet where "SourceData" named range is the currently _active_ one. Moreover, while in VBA IDE step through code with F8 and use Immediate Window (CTRL to pop it out) to query relevant data (e.g. type `?i` and press return to see current `i` variable value. or while inside `For j = 1 To...` loop,  type `?data(i,j)` and press return to see current `data(i,j)` value, and so on

Comment: These are my current times:
Rows Pasted            Cells/row                Time                rows/sec
1000                    24                                00:01:39        10,10
2500                    24                                00:04:35          9,09
5000                    24                                00:10:21          8,05
7500                    24                                00:19:43          6,34
10000                    24                                00:28:39          5,82

Comment: I am starting the macro with a button from the sheet where my range 'SourceData' is located (the values that need to be copied). For the rest i can't adapt the macro to work :(  It runs, but nothing happens.

Comment: then _Moreover, while in VBA IDE step through code with F8 and use Immediate Window (CTRL to pop it out) to query relevant data (e.g. type `?i` and press return to see current `i` variable value. or while inside For j = 1 To... loop, type `?data(i,j)` and press return to see current `data(i,j)` value, and so on_